# Navigation sidebar vuex + typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, navigation, vuex, sidebar

everyone!

How to make a sidebar navigator using veux + typescript?

I'm stuck and I don't know how to move on.. help me, dear, patient developers

using vue3 (Composition API setup) + Typescript + Tailwind CSS

Can u help me?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gz3xe.png)

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "kalys.io",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@heroicons/vue": "^1.0.6",
    "@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat": "^2.2.17",
    "autoprefixer": "^9",
    "chart.js": "^3.7.1",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "heroicons": "^1.0.6",
    "postcss": "^7",
    "query-string": "^7.1.1",
    "tailwindcss": "npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat@^2.2.17",
    "vue": "^3.0.0",
    "vue-chartjs": "^4.1.0",
    "vue-google-maps-typescript": "^0.1.4",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.0-0",
    "vueperslides": "^3.3.2",
    "vuex": "^4.0.0-0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0",
    "typescript": "~4.1.5",
    "vue-cli-plugin-tailwind": "^2.2.18"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead"
  ]
}
```

inside **store/index.ts**

```
import {
  createStore,
  Store as VuexStore,
  CommitOptions,
  createLogger,
  DispatchOptions
} from 'vuex'

import { State, state } from './modules/state'
import { Mutations, mutations } from './modules/mutations'
import { Actions, actions } from './modules/actions'
import { Getters, getters } from './modules/getters'

export const store = createStore<State>({
  plugins: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? [createLogger()] : [],
  state,
  mutations,
  actions,
  getters,

  modules: {
  }
})

export function useStore() {
  return store as Store
}
export type Store = Omit<
VuexStore<State>,
'getters' | 'commit' | 'dispatch'
> & {
  commit<K extends keyof Mutations, P extends Parameters<Mutations[K]>[1]>(
    key: K,
    payload: P,
    options?: CommitOptions
  ): ReturnType<Mutations[K]>
} & {
  dispatch<K extends keyof Actions>(
    key: K,
    payload?: Parameters<Actions[K]>[1],
    options?: DispatchOptions
  ): ReturnType<Actions[K]>
} & {
  getters: {
    [K in keyof Getters]: ReturnType<Getters[K]>
  }
}
```

inside **store/modules/state.ts**

```
export type State = {
  theme: string;
  showSidebar: boolean;
};

export const state: State = reactive({
  theme: 'light',
  showSidebar: true
});
```

inside **store/modules/mutation-types.ts**

```
export enum MutationTypes {
  SET_THEME = 'SET_THEME',
  SET_SHOWSIDEBAR = 'SET_SHOWSIDEBAR'
}
```

inside **store/modules/mutation.ts**

```
import { MutationTree } from "vuex";
import { MutationTypes } from "./mutation-types";
import { State } from './state';

export type Mutations<S = State> = {
  [MutationTypes.SET_THEME](state: S, payload: string | boolean): void;
  [MutationTypes.SET_SHOWSIDEBAR](state: S, payload: boolean): void;
}

export const mutations: MutationTree<State> & Mutations = {
  [MutationTypes.SET_THEME](state: State, payload: string) {
    state.theme = payload,
    localStorage.theme = payload
  },
  [MutationTypes.SET_SHOWSIDEBAR](state: State, payload: boolean) {
    state.showSidebar = payload
  },
}
```

inside **store/modules/action-types.ts**

```
export enum ActionTypes {
  INIT_THEME = 'INIT_THEME',
  toggle_theme = 'TOGGLE_THEME',
  toggle_sidebar = 'TOGGLE_SIDEBAR'
}
```

inside **store/modules/action.ts**

```
import { MutationTypes } from './mutation-types';
import { ActionContext, ActionTree } from "vuex";
import { ActionTypes } from "./action-types";
import { Mutations } from "./mutations";
import { State } from "./state";

type ActionAugments = Omit<ActionContext<State, State>, 'commit'> & {
  commit<K extends keyof Mutations>(
    key: K,
    payload: Parameters<Mutations[K]>[1]
  ): ReturnType<Mutations[K]>
}

export type Actions = {
  [ActionTypes.INIT_THEME](context: ActionAugments): void;
}

export const actions: ActionTree<State, State> & Actions = {
  [ActionTypes.INIT_THEME]({ commit }) {
    const cachedTheme: boolean = localStorage.theme ? localStorage.theme : false;

    const userPrefersDark = window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches;

    if(cachedTheme) {
      commit(MutationTypes.SET_THEME, cachedTheme)
    } else if(userPrefersDark) {
      commit(MutationTypes.SET_THEME, 'dark')
    } else {
      commit(MutationTypes.SET_THEME, 'light')
    }
  },

  
  [ActionTypes.toggle_theme]({ commit }) {


    switch (localStorage.theme) {
      case 'light':
        commit('SET_THEME', 'dark')
        break;
    
      default:
        commit('SET_THEME', 'light')
        break;
    }
  },

  [ActionTypes.toggle_sidebar]({ commit }, state) {

    let sidebar = MutationTypes.SET_SHOWSIDEBAR ? false : true;
    commit(MutationTypes.SET_SHOWSIDEBAR, sidebar)
  }
}
```

inside **store/modules/getters.ts**

```
import { GetterTree } from "vuex";
import { State } from './state';

export type Getters = {
  GET_THEME(state: State): string 
  GET_SHOWSIDEBAR(state: State): boolean
}
export const getters: GetterTree<State, State> & Getters = {
  GET_THEME(state) {
    return state.theme;
  },
  
  GET_SHOWSIDEBAR(state) {
    return state.showSidebar;
  },
}
```

**Components/TheHeaderUpNav.vue**
At the bottom I connect the sidebar and sidebar switch button (, )

```
<template>
  <div
    class="top-0 fixed lg:relative z-50 flex lg:justify-center justify-end items-center w-full py-1 lg:px-1 bg-gray-900 text-gray-300"
  >
    <div
      class="flex justify-between w-full text-xs md:text-sm lg:justify-around lg:gap-4 xl:gap-16"
    >
      <ul class="hidden lg:flex justify-around font-semibold py-2 text-xs xl:text-sm">
        <li class="xl:mx-3" v-for="(navup, index) in navups" :key="index">
          <router-link
            :to="navup.to"
            class="text-gray-300 px-3 py-2 rounded-sm hover:border-b-2 hover:border-white"
          >
            {{ navup.title }}
          </router-link>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div class="flex items-center mx-5 sm:mr-20 lg:hidden">
        <TheMobileButtonHumburger />
        <div class="mx-3 flex xs:hidden">LOGO</div>
      </div>

      <div class="hidden items-center 2xl:flex">Пн-Пт. 9:00 - 17:30</div>
      <div class="flex mx-5 lg:mx-0">
        <div class="lg:hidden flex items-center">
          <MultiLanguage />
        </div>
        <div class="flex items-center right-0 py-1">
          <TheToggleTheme />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <TheMobileSidebar />
</template>
<script lang="ts" setup>
  import TheMobileButtonHumburger from "./TheMobileButtonHumburger.vue";
  import TheMobileSidebar from "./TheMobileSidebar.vue";
<script/>
```

The component itself looks like this. **Components/TheMobileSidebar.vue**

```
<template>
  <div
    class="flex flex-col lg:hidden w-[300px] h-[100%] px-5 py-20 xs:py-10 text-gray-300 bg-black z-30 fixed bg-opacity-50 backdrop-filter backdrop-blur-lg"
    :class="{ '-left-full': !isShowSidebar }"
  >
    <ul class="w-full h-full" v-for="(navup, id) in navups" :key="id">
      <li>{{ navup.title }}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
import { useStore } from "@/store";
import { ref } from "vue";

const store = useStore();
const navups = store.getters.GET_NAVUPS;
let isShowSidebar = ref(store.getters.GET_SHOWSIDEBAR);

//const theme = computed(() => store.getters.GET_THEME);

// watch(isShowSidebar, (newSidebar, oldSidebar) => {
//   const toggleSidebar = store.getters.GET_SHOWSIDEBAR;

//   newSidebar === false
//     ? commit(MutationTypes.SET_SHOWSIDEBAR, true)
//     : commit(MutationTypes.SET_SHOWSIDEBAR, false);
// });

// console.log(isShowSidebar);
</script>
```

The button itself looks like this **Components/TheMobileButtonHumburger.vue**

```
<template>
  <button class="cursor-pointer border-2 border-white rounded-md" @click="toggleSidebar">
    <svg
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      class="h-5 w-5"
      fill="none"
      viewBox="0 0 24 24"
      stroke="currentColor"
    >
      <path
        stroke-linecap="round"
        stroke-linejoin="round"
        stroke-width="2"
        d="M4 6h16M4 12h16M4 18h7"
      />
    </svg>
  </button>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { ActionTypes } from "@/store/modules/action-types";
import { defineComponent } from "vue";
import { useStore } from "vuex";

export default defineComponent({
  name: "toggleSidebar",
  setup() {
    const store = useStore();

    const toggleSidebar = () => {
      store.dispatch(ActionTypes.toggle_sidebar);
      console.log(store.getters.GET_SHOWSIDEBAR);
    };

    return { toggleSidebar };
  },
});
</script>
```

Comment: I've only skimmed this question but it is not immediately clear what's not working. Can you pin down your problem more precisely and maybe package your code so it runs and shows the problem? Have a read of https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for inspiration.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: When the screen is reduced, that is, when mobile, the side sidebar is displayed. and worked through clicking the hamburger menu. This should be implemented through vuex+ts. 
In state, I already have showSidebar: boolean; and this, when clicked, I reactively changed from true to false and back.
Help me, please!